# Attempting to render to multiple attributes to a single JSX element from an object - React component

Tags: reactjs

I've saved some data to two arrays in an object, and I want to iterate over both arrays to two attributes of a single JSX element.

My specific use case, I'm getting data from an API which I'm using to render multiple images. 
I have one array in an object which gives me the image URLs.
I have another array in the same object which gives me the alt text for the same image.
Both arrays are the same length.

I want to iterate through both arrays and render data from both to the same image element.

I successfully iterated over a single array using .map into an image element, and rendered as many images as I expected to see.
I then tried using Object.entries, but I still end up with two arrays.

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  state = {
      photo: {
        img: [url1, url2, url3, url4],
        alt: [string1, string2, string3, string4] 
      },
    };

  render () {
    return(
      //currently only maps one array. Need to figure out how to map from two arrays
      this.state.photo.map((img, key) => {
        <Image img={this.state.photo.img} alt={this.state.photo.alt} key={key} />
      })
    )
  }
}
```

expected result is several image components with url and alt text taken from the two arrays img and url in object photo.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data structure to be an array of objects rather than two arrays.

Your array should look like this:

```js
let images = [{image: url1, alt: alt1}, {image: url2, alt: al2 } ...etc.]
```

It will then be much easier to map those variables now:

```
this.state.images.map((x, index) => {
  <Image img={x.image} alt={x.alt} key={index} />
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you're right my data structure wasn't helping me. I ended up solving this with the following

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  state = {
      photo: [{image: url1, alt: alt1}, {image: url2, alt: al2 } ...etc],
    };

  render () {
    const images = this.state.photo.map((photo) =>
      <Image img={photo.image} alt={photo.alt} />
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {images}
      </div>
    )
}
```